# Installing Sophos VPN client on MacOS

Tags: mac, vpn, installer, sophos

I am completely unfamiliar with MacOS. So when faced with trying to install the Sophos VPN client On someone's Laptop I've hit a brick wall.

The installer ends with the extension .ovpn. Mac OS attempts to open this in Acrobat so my feeling was that if I renamed the installer with a different extension this may begin the installation process.

I have tried .zip, .app, .exe, .pkg and .dmg.

Other than changing the extension, I don't know what to try.

Comment: No installer has the extension .ovpn That's a config document for a pre-installed VPN solution. See https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000036421?language=en_US

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, that's very helpful. Given that the other downloads we have access to are installers we assumed that this would be too. I will source an installer then import the file.

Comment: @Ar77 The only OpenVPN installer Sophos offers, AFAIK, is a Windows `.exe` that installs the public OpenVPN client [rebranded w/ Sophos' logo] and installs the `.ovpn` config file in the appropriate directory _(if they do offer installers for other platforms, it would likely do the same)_. Also, a general FYI, I've found it's better to customize the default client and server [configs](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN) _(server: `/var/sec/chroot-openvpn/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf-default`)_, as Sophos didn't have crucial options in the WebAdmin as of last year

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tetsujin I understand the issue.
THe file I have isn't an installer, it's a config file. So we installed the openVpn client on the Mac and imported the .ovpn configuration which opened up the vpn.